# How to detect java installation from a batch program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jvm

I want to run a jar file on a client machine using batch script. But the problem is its not clear where is the java installed. There are 3-4 fixed paths where java.exe can exist.

How to write a batch script to find where java is installed on any of those predetermined locations and then run a command to execute a jar file.

Assume java is not set in the environment variables and no access to windows registry.

Comment: Well at least one valid java *should* be set in the environment variables, as per `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`... if you can't rely on this as a minimum then you have a problem with your machines...

Answer (score 1):

On windows :

```
c:\> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

On linux:

```
$ which java
```